# How to slide a vertex with UV to avoid stretching?

Tags: modeling, uv

I would like to move some vertices of a plane created through the "import image as plane", but without stretching the texture. A kind of crop like in libreoffice writer.

Side-notes:

Best would be a trunk function but if their is no such function, a way to move the vertex in both 3D view and UV editor (an add-on or with some conversion maybe ? Like 3Dview_vertex_move(x,y)*(a factor)=UV_vertex_move(x2,y2) ) at the same time would be nice.

I know the knife tool can do the job somehow, but it involves many more steps (deleting old vertices, etc...). I'm looking for an efficient solution as I have to do it a lot.

Comment: Before I read the last paragraph I thought "use the knife tool". From what I know, it's the way to do it.

Comment: Have you tried a Boolean Modifier? You can make a knock-out shape and thicken (extrude) it so that it overlaps the Image Plane above and below. It works, but you have to delete some remnants of the shape object. It all depends on what you are really trying to do.

Comment: @SteveW What a shame it doesn't work with 2 2D objects, it would do the trick, but yes, the involved cleaning brings the same problem as the knife tool :(

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about programming it in, but here is how I would do it.
After importing the image go ahead and put in your loop cuts or whatever where you want to crop the image to.

This distorts the image. To fix that, just re-unwrap it.
The command is `bpy.ops.uv.unwrap()`
Or you can hit <kbd>W</kbd> > *Unwrap*.

Then just delete the outside vertices and you will get a cropped image.

Comment: it may work, but it's longer than using knife and has the same problem (deleting edges, having to start and finish on an existing edge, etc...), so for 100s of images like in my case, it would take ages.